# Magento invoice grid filter by joined attribute value

Tags: magento

I'm using the following code to include a custom attribute, titled "sales rep" within the Magento invoice grid:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {   

    $sales_rep = Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('sales_rep');

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_grid_collection');
    $collection->join('invoice', 'main_table.entity_id = invoice.entity_id',array('order_id as order_id'));
    $collection->join('order', 'invoice.order_id = order.entity_id',array('customer_id as customer_id'));

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
      array('customer_sales_rep_table' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($sales_rep->getBackend()->getTable())),
      'customer_sales_rep_table.entity_id = order.customer_id
        AND customer_sales_rep_table.attribute_id = '.(int) $sales_rep->getAttributeId() . '
      ',
      array('sales_rep'=>'value')
      );      

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();

}
```

...

```
$this->addColumn('sales_rep', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sales Rep'),
    'index' => 'sales_rep',
    'filter' => false
));
```

This is working perfectly, just as long as the "addColumn" property "filter" is set to "false".

How would I go about allowing users to filter by this joined attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your column like this:

```
$this->addColumn('sales_rep', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sales Rep'),
    'index' => 'sales_rep',
    'filter_index' => 'customer_sales_rep_table.value'
));
```